# How to Add (Not Edit) bytes anywhere in another process memory

Tags: c#, memory

I have tried WriteProcessMemory but it replaces the memory not add.

I'm trying to use it to redirect connection for online game by setting sockaddr options.
(if there another way I don't mind).

I think this is the full information.

Comment: Some information about what specifically you are trying to accomplish might help you get some answers.

Comment: Do you want to intercept function calls and replace them with your own? or are you talking about editing values of variables in memory? Please add more details to explain exactly what you are trying to accomplis. You are falling in to the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please ask us how to complete your goal, not how to complete problem with the solution you think will get you to your goal.

Comment: All Answers is helpful but I've tried VirtualAllocEx and the function failed

Comment: If you just want to change the server that it connects to you could just set the dns name to a different ip address in the [hosts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) file

Comment: no i need redirect not programmly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are wanting to intercept calls to the socket system and replace them with your own values you can do that with [EasyHook](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/).

EasyHook is a managed C# wrapper to make intercepting function calls that a exe makes to other dll's. So you could intercept the call to [WSAConnect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740506%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and modify the value of `sockaddr` before it gets passed on to windows.

If you need help figuring out *which* dll's and api calls you need to intercept I recommend the tool [API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor). It is still technically "alpha" but it works really well.

Answer (score 2):

To allocate memory on another process you can use `VirtualAllocEx()` and then you can use `WriteProcessMemory()` to write into your allocation.